# DSL implementation() not found despite all requirements fullfilled

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm updating Android Studio, Gradle and the gradle plugin in my project, because I want to implement MoPub.

MoPub only seems to work with the new versions of gradle, so I finally have to upgrade from 2.3 to 3.4.x

I did so, I even updated Android Studio, but still, when I synch the project, the DSL implementation() is not found.

my build.gradle (Project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode ...
        versionName "..."
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter() // includes the MoPub SDK and AVID library
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implmementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk:+@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I get the following message when synching:

> ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implmementation()'
>   Possible causes:  
>   The project '...' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
>   *Upgrade plugin to version 3.4.1 and sync project*  
>   The project '...' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   *Open Gradle wrapper file*  
>   The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   *Apply Gradle plugin*

When I click the first hint to upgrade the plugin I get an error, propably because I already use 3.4.1
When I click the second one the `gradle-wrapper.properties` opens, but I use `gradle-5.1.1-all.zip`, which is the newest one, right?
And when I click the last hint a popup opens which offers a ton of plugins I could implement into the app Module.

Why does Gradle not find `implementation()`, even though I have all the required versions etc.? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the `build.gradle`, you need to change the following:

```
implmementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
```

into this:

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
```

You have an extra `m`.

Comment: Thank you, this is embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implmementation()'

Check the error message. There is a **typo**.

Use

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
```

instead of

```
implmementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
```